# How can i pass useState value from child to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-context

I am having two child components where they have a separate state. Now I want to use the state in the two-child components and render it in the parent. how can I do it

```
function ChildA() {
  const [solutestate, setsolutestate] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <Jsme
        height="300px"
        width="400px"
        options="oldlook,star"
        onChange={setsolutestate}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const childB = () => {
  const [solventstate, setsolventstate] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <Jsme
        height="300px"
        width="400px"
        options="oldlook,star"
        onChange={setsolventstate}
      />
    </div>
  );
};


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />

      <div>{solutestate}</div>
      <div>{solventstate}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your text basically tells us that this is not child state at all, but the parent's state, and actions in the children should trigger that state change in the parent, not in the children. They might get the event, but they should handle it by calling a props-passed handler function that the parent gave them, which lets the parent set that value for itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should save the state in the parent(called lifting the state up) and then pass down the setters to the children.

```js
function ChildA({ setsolutestateA}) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Jsme
          height="300px"
          width="400px"
          options="oldlook,star"
          onChange={setsolutestateA}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  const childB = ({{ setsolutestateB}}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Jsme
          height="300px"
          width="400px"
          options="oldlook,star"
          onChange={setsolutestateB}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  
  function App() {
    const [solutestateA, setsolutestateA] = useState("");
    const [solutestateB, setsolutestateB] = useState("");

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ChildA {...{setsolutestateA}}/>
        <ChildB {...{setsolutestateB}}/>
  
        <div>{solutestateA}</div>
        <div>{solutestateB}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, It solved my problem but can you give more explanation on how it worked and the using `...{}` got the value

Comment: its just javascript destructuring, you can read more at MDN, it's just a shorthand syntax for passing many props down. however, don't overuse it as it can damage performance(each destructure a new object is created)

Comment: You are using two `{{}}` in childB is it on purpose or mistake. and I am getting the output but it is getting repeated. What should I have to do?

Comment: provide working code sandbox  so i could help you

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a function setting the state from your parent to child component, so the child can update the parent's state with the call of a function passed with props.

Ex:
Parent:

```
function App() {
  const [solventstate, setsolventstate] = useState("");

  const sendDataToParent = (solventstate) => { // the callback. Use a better name
    setsolventstate(solventstate);
  }
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChildA sendDataToParent={sendDataToParent}/>
      <ChildB sendDataToParent={sendDataToParent}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child:

```
const childB = ({sendDataToParent}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Jsme
        height="300px"
        width="400px"
        options="oldlook,star"
        onChange={sendDataToParent(solventstate)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}:
```